# Django: How to create a simple view to display current object of a model?

Tags: django

models.py:

```
class User(models.Model):
    sex_choices=(('M', 'Male'), ('F', 'Female'))
    category_choices=(('S', 'Student'),('T', 'Teacher'),('G', 'Guardian'))
    qual_choices = (('a', 'Secondary'),('b', 'Senior Secondary'),('c', 'Undergraduate'),('d', 'Postgraduate'))
    area_choices = (('CS', 'Computer Science'),('Maths', 'Mathematics'),('Phy', 'Physics'),('Chem','Chemistry'),('Bio', 'Biology')) 

    first_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    last_name = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    age = models.PositiveSmallIntegerField()
    sex = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=sex_choices)
    contact = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    email = models.EmailField(unique=True)

    category = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=category_choices)
    qualification = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=qual_choices)
    area = models.CharField(max_length=5, choices=area_choices, null=True)  
    current_institution = models.CharField(max_length=30)
    about = models.TextField(null=True)

    password = models.CharField(max_length=20)
```

views.py:

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        return context
```

urls.py:

```
urlpatterns = [
url(r'^profile/(?P<slug>[-\w]+)/$', views.UserDetailView.as_view(), name='profile')]
```

templates/profile.html:

```
<font size="6" color="white">Name: {{object.first_name}} {{object.last_name}}</font>
```

I simply want to display the details of the current user i.e. display the fields of an object of class User. I can't figure out how to create a view for the same. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your `UserDetailView` you need to call `get_object()` to get the particular object:

```
class UserDetailView(DetailView):
    model = User

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super(UserDetailView, self).get_context_data(**kwargs)
        user = super(UserDetailView, self).get_object()
        context['user'] = user

        return context
```

> **Note**
>
> In your url you've used `slug` as the user/profile identifier. Unless I'm mistaken that's not a PK field in your model. Django's `DetailView` requires a value that is a representation of the PK of the model. E.g. If your model has field `UUID` as PK then the url should have a valid uuid in it so that Django can get the object. If `slug` has been used as a named group, (`DetailView` uses `pk` as the default), then you need to set the `pk_url_kwarg` in your view to `slug` i.e. `pk_url_kwarg = 'slug'`.

References:

- [Class-Based Generic Views](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/)